# What better way to show a list of online users in the rtmfp (cirrus) group

Tags: adobe, rtmfp, adobe-cirrus

What better way to show a list of online users in the rtmfp (cirrus) group?
For example in this project http://www.flashrealtime.com/simple-chat-p2p-netgroup-rtmfp/.

Initial registration is not difficult (it`s can do  easy like  exchanging messages between rtmfp cirrus nodes at the time of entry in the group), but there is a problem of how to perform monitoring of already registered users. Perhaps there are standard mechanisms, such as a list of all peers of cirrus group, or other technology?

Answer (score 0):

`netGroup.neighborCount` is what you are exactly looking for.
You could find more info here.
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/636089

Comment: I guess that neighbours in rtmfp group not mean all user of this group.
And I have additional question, how I can know about new connected peer in rtmfp group. I know only about `NetGroup.Neighbor.Connect` event, but after reading this article  http://www.flashrealtime.com/directed-routing-explained-flash-p2p/ 
I'm afraid that it may sometimes not work.